# Any way to store a LINQ expression as a property?

Tags: c#, linq, properties

Basically, I want to be able to create an Object and pass in a LINQ query to it as a property and store that property...

I know I could always just run the LINQ query in the code that wants to filter a collection, but I thought it'd be interesting if my Object could retain that query so that other classes that reference it can grab that query...

---

Pseudo-Code

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(?? linq)
    {
        TheLinq = linq;
    }

    public ?? TheLinq { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could store the Query as Action ,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Comment: What type of query were you thinking of?

Comment: Any type of query... using Where, OrderBy, Intersect, etc. I wanna be able to pass in an expression that gets evaluated when I need it to be.

Comment: Are we talking delegates or expression-trees here?

Comment: @Ani: I'm not sure which... I'll update my question with pseudo-code for what I desire.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something very close to the following:

```
public class Program {
  private static void Main(string[] args) {
    Func<List<string>, IEnumerable> testQuery = x => x.Where<IEnumerable>(y => !y.Equals("Yucky"));
    var testArray=new string[] {"Hello", "Yucky", " ", "World"};

    var testClass=new MyClass(testQuery);
    var resultStrings = testClass.query(testArray.ToList());

    // Printing resultStrings should result in "Hello World"
    foreach (string s in resultStrings) {
       Console.Write(s);
    }
   }
}


public class MyClass {
  public Func<List<string>, IEnumerable> query { get; private set; }

  public MyClass(Func<List<string>, IEnumerable> aQuery)
  {
    query=aQuery;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Checked, and yes this does work

In general, you will need to tailor the `Func<input, output>` as you would like it to end up, but this should work perfectly well for you, I should think!

And just for a little bit of read-ability, the func here could be rewritten with less ambiguous variable names like: `Func<List<string>, IEnumerable> testQuery = theListToQuery => theListToQuery.Where<IEnumerable>(stringInList => !stringInList.Equals("Yucky"));`

Comment: No. I'm looking to pass the entire LINQ expression, not parts of it. I don't know for sure if I'm going to use a LINQ Where function or a OrderBy, etc.

Comment: @michael Well you could always have arguments that account for each of these and just leave the ones you don't want null, or do method signature overloading. Can you come up with a situation in which you need to set a class-wide Linq query in which it shouldn't be in a function or directly in the code? This seems pretty obscure, though I suppose I can imagine an instance in which you would want to do this. If so, I do think that Cody is right and you should look into Actions

Comment: I have a scenario... I want to be able to pass the **expression** itself, then evaluate it. I don't want to account for every possible scenario with hundreds of methods and a crazy amount of if/then statements. I want to simply do: `MyClass = new MyClass(myLinqExpression);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to retain the query expression and manipulate it, consider the following:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public MyClass(IQueryable<MyClass> linq) 
    { 
        TheLinq = linq; 
    } 

    public IQueryable<MyClass> TheLinq { get; set; } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use Expression Trees. The Expression objects (expr and expr1) are instances of the type you are trying to explain above. These expression objects can be passed around and compiled as necessary:

```
            List<int> ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<int>>> expr = x=> x.Where(y=> y>6);

        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool,int>>>> expr1 = x => x.GroupBy(y => y > 6);

        // first expression
        var bobs = expr.Compile()(ints);

        foreach(var bob in bobs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bob);
        }
        // second expression
        var bobs1 = expr1.Compile()(ints);
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (IGrouping<bool, int> bob in bobs1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("group " + counter++ + " values :");
            foreach (var t in bob)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t);
            }

        }
```